# Django: Views problem with Django + django-registration + jinja

Tags: django, jinja2, django-registration

So, I have a django project that is using jinja2 rendering, and I also installed django-registration to make my life easier. I ran into the following problem:

Going to homepage I render it with jinja. In order to check for authentication, I have to use jinja's syntax, which is user.is_authenticated(). However, in regular django templating, this check is done with user.is_authenticated. If in regular django templating there are (), it gives error.

So going to the /accounts/login/ page, the django-registration modul doesn't do anything special, so it forwards the url to the standard django views the following way:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

url(r'^login/$',
auth_views.login,
{'template_name': 'registration/login.html'},
name='auth_login'),
```

So I know for sure I shouldn't be changing the django.contrib.auth view, but then where do i put my own view? In myapp/views.py?

And also, do I have to copy paste the django view, and then modify on top of it (in this case simply replace the render with render_jinja) or is there a way to 'extend' this original django view to my own slightly modified view for logging in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether right or wrong, in the registration module, I made a new view, that handled the logging, copying a few lines from here and there. It logical and seems to be working fine.